# async/await not working in reactjs (used npx create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Currently, the `console.log()` in `makeQuery()` is returning the correct object while the `console.log()` in `scoop()` is returning "undefined" as the definition of `response` in `scoop()` is not waiting for the function call to `makeQuery()` to return.

I would like for the definition of `response` in `scoop()` to wait for the function call to `makeQuery()` before the code below runs.

How do I make this happen?

```
var request = require('request');

const makeQuery = (query) => {
  request('http://0.0.0.0:4000/wikiweb?text=' + query, function (error, response, body) {
      var jason = JSON.parse(body)
      console.log(jason)
      return jason
    }
  )

class Wiki extends React.Component {



  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.scoop = this.scoop.bind(this);
    this.state = {loaded: false}
  }

  scoop = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = this.textInput.value;
    var response = await makeQuery(query);
    console.log(response)
    // await this.setState({data : response, loaded : true});
    // console.log(this.state.data)
  } 

...
```

Comment: You do not return anything from `makeQuery` and as of that the returned value `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return a promise from the `makeQuery` function or there will be no promise to use `await` on and it will resolve immediately.

**Example**

```
const makeQuery = query => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    request("http://0.0.0.0:4000/wikiweb?text=" + query, function(
      error,
      response,
      body
    ) {
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(json);
      resolve(json);
    });
  });
};

class Wiki extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scoop = this.scoop.bind(this);
    this.state = { loaded: false };
  }

  scoop = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = this.textInput.value;
    var response = await makeQuery(query);
    console.log(response);
  };

  // ...
}
```

Comment: This causes the request to return though, not the body of the request.

Comment: @TadeoYelos That's not true. I'm resolving the promise with the response, `resolve(json);`

Comment: Yeah, you're right actually. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, the problem is that makeQuery() is requesting to the URL but not waiting for the response from the URL. You need to make makeQuery() also an async/await function.

```
var request = require('request');

const makeQuery = async (query) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request("http://0.0.0.0:4000/wikiweb?text=" + query, function (error,response,body) {

      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      var json = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(json);
      resolve(json);
    });
  })
}

class Wiki extends React.Component {



  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.scoop = this.scoop.bind(this);
    this.state = { loaded: false }
  }

  scoop = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = this.textInput.value;
    var response = await makeQuery(query);
    console.log(response)
    // await this.setState({data : response, loaded : true});
    // console.log(this.state.data)
  }
}
```

Comment: `request` doesn't return a promise, so `await request('http://0.0.0.0:4000/wikiweb?text=' + query);` will not work as expected.

Comment: In that case, return a promise from makeQuery()

Comment: Updated the code